# Spread for an object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spread

I have an array of objects and I want it to become an object that would go `{ 44: "autoTest", 94: "autoTest", ...}`

```
[
  0: {
    id: 1, 
    name: "test", 
    description: "a description"
  }, 
  1: {
    id: 2, 
    name: "test 2", 
    description: "a description french baguette"
  }
]
```

would become

```
{
  1: "test", 
  2: "test2"
}
```

My code so far with some console.log() :

```
const { options } = this.state;
console.log(options); // […] 0: Object { id: 44, name: "autoTest", description: "test uniUpdate", … } 1: Object { id: 94, name: "autoTest", description: "test uni", … }
​let obj2 = {};
if (options.length > 0) {
  options.map((item, key) => {
    const id = item.id;
    const name = item.name;
    let obj1 = { [id]: name };
    console.log(obj1); // Object { 44: "autoTest" } for example
    obj2 = { ...obj1 };
  });
  console.log(obj2); // Object { 16: "Test 3" } is called like two times and is obviously not what I expected
}
```

Some hints ?

Comment: I think you wanted to use a `forEach` or even a `reduce`

Comment: `obj2 = {...obj2, ...obj1}`

Comment: `obj2 = Object.assign(obj2, obj1)`

Comment: Why do you want this to be an object instead of an array?

Comment: @YannickK Likely because the IDs aren't necessarily contiguous.

Comment: @Mowso because the function `map` is being used in a misunderstood way.  The function `Array.prototype.map` creates a new array with mapped/transformed elements from the source array.  Read about [Functors](https://hackernoon.com/functors-in-javascript-20a647b8f39f) `(:`

Comment: `obj2 = Object.fromEntries(options.map(({id, name})=> [id,name]))`

Comment: i don't get the question tbh - you want the array index as new object key and the values should be the ones from the `name` attribute in the array objects?

Comment: and this is not really a question about `react`

Comment: @Ele As you solve my issue I would suggest you'd write an answer + link the thing on why map is used in you wrong way, if you may

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not need to be so complex. You can simplify it by using `reduce()`:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1, 
    name: "test", 
    description: "a description"
  }, 
  {
    id: 2, 
    name: "test 2", 
    description: "a description french baguette"
  }
]

const result = data.reduce((a, { id, name }) => ({ ...a, [id]: name }), {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be using the array method called `forEach` to loop through each value (in this case object) in the array

```
const arr = [{id: 1, name: "test", description: "a description"}, {id: 2, name: "test 2", description: "a description french baguette"}]

const newObj = {}

arr.forEach(item => newObj[item.id] = item.name)
// console.log(newObj) >>>>>> {1: "test", 2: "test 2"}
```

I feel this is self-explanatory. Let me know if any part is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simplified with `map` and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), or `reduce` :

```js
var arr = [ { id: 1, name: "test"  , description: "a description" }, 
            { id: 2, name: "test 2", description: "a description french baguette" } ]

var obj1 = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(o => [o.id, o.name]))

var obj2 = arr.reduce((o, v) => (o[v.id] = v.name, o), {})

console.log( obj1 )
console.log( obj2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've stated, you should use a `forEach` or even a `reduce` function.

```js
let arr = [{id: 1, name: "test", description: "a description"}, {id: 2, name: "test 2", description: "a description french baguette"}],
    result = arr.reduce((a, {id, name}) => Object.assign(a, {[id]: name}), Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach with forEach() and the spread operator:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1, 
    name: "test", 
    description: "a description"
  }, 
  {
    id: 2, 
    name: "test 2", 
    description: "a description french baguette"
  }
];

let output = {};
data.forEach((item) => {output = {...output, [item.id]: item.name};});
```

output: `{ 1: "test", 2: "test 2" }`